# VS Code debugger does not show variables python

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, debugging

Why cannot see the variables drop down menu anymore in VS code debugger with python. I already updated vscode, and reinstalled the python extensions. Did not fix it.

Ubuntu 20.04 with vscode 1.79.2

[Vs code without variables in debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJVcc.png)

Comment: what Python interpreter are you using and where did you install it from?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue. I'm also using Ubuntu 20 and the latest VSCode. You could try to install another version of the Python extension or select another Python interpreter in VSCode.